# In the context of time-complexity, how do you calculate the number of times a loop will iterate?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation

I am doing competition programming and as a part of this, we also have written packets we do. There are times when tracing through code is not the fastest route and using a formula is more time efficient. I have written a formula for the following:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
      for (int j = i; j < X; j++)
```

This loop will iterate in accordance with this formula:
$$\frac{X^2+X}{2}$$

```
 for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
      for (int j = i; j < B; j++)
```

However, when working with a different constant for the two loops I am at a loss for finding a formula. So far the best I have come up with is using summation where A and B are the two constants in the loops.
$$\sum_{x_1=0}^{A}{(\sum_{x_2=x_1}^{B}{1})}$$
How can I reduce and simplify this to something similar to the first equation?

Comment: Is $A \leq B$? Please elaborate

Comment: Yes, A is less than or equal to B.

Comment: So then your answer is $B + (B - 1) + (B - 2) + \dots + (B - A + 1)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the pedantic computation isn't impossible $$\sum_{i=0}^{A-1}\sum_{j=i}^{B-1}1=\sum_{i=0}^{A-1}\max(B-1-i+1,0)=\sum_{i=0}^{A-1}\max(B-i,0)=\begin{cases}\sum_{i=0}^{A-1}B-i&\text{if }B\ge A-1\\ \sum_{i=0}^B B-i&\text{if }B<A-1\end{cases}=\\=\begin{cases}(A-1-0+1)B-\frac{A(A-1)}2&\text{if }B\ge A-1\\ (B-0+1)B-\frac{B(B+1)}2&\text{if }B<A-1\end{cases}=\begin{cases}AB-\frac{A^2}2+\frac A2&\text{if }B\ge A-1\\ \frac{B^2+B}2&\text{if }B<A-1\end{cases}$$

And here it kind of depends on how $A$ and $B$ relate in the general problem and tricks. I would write this asymptotic complexity as $\Theta(B\cdot\min(A,B))$.